# Spring boot starter security - missing RsaKeyConverters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to use `spring-boot-startet-security` with JWT and OAuth.

I used this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) to get a base to work with. There's an error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/converter/RsaKeyConverters" Exception` at the beginning of the starting process of my application.

I think I am missing a dependency. I already tried `spring-security-config` and `spring-security-core`, but it didn't work.

Do I need to provide the `RsaKeyConverters` class by itself?

Thanks for your help!

**POM**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>auth0-spring-security-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just had this problem myself, this sorted for me.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```